# CSS - Border bottom length fixed to 60%

Tags: css

I need help on border-bottom length. I want to set border-bottom length to 60%. I can do it using the inner div like:

```css
#myDiv {
  background: #FED;
  _border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
#myDiv div {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  My div
  <div></div>
</div>
```

But i don't want to use it with extra div, I want to achieve it using border-bottom, I search for this in google and stack but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) like this:

```css
#myDiv {
  background: #FED;
  position: relative;
  
}
#myDiv::after {
  content: "";
  width: 60%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  My div
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but you miss the `display: block` properties..

Comment: without `display: block`, just using the positions.. Wonderful. Which one is best?? `display` or `position`??

Comment: You may use at your own choice.